# Assign Role not based on userid values in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I am trying some thing like this to assign a role to a user based on User Identity values he has.

```
use yii\rbac\PhpManager;
$r=new PhpManager;
$r->init();
$r->createRole("admin","Administrator");
```

It has a function named assign to assign role :

```
$r->assign('1','admin');
```

But I need to assign role value based on the User Identity values or any other condition like `if($a=='somevalue')` he should be assigned a role called 'admin'.
How can it be achieved ?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, it should be handled via rules. You can find example [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#using-rules).

Comment: I want to assign roles at the time of login, not checking the role

Answer (score 0):

In short: you need to extend yii\web\User class and redefine its 'can()' method.

Lets say you need to check user by 'group_id'.

1. Create new class

   ```
   namespace app\models;

   class User extends yii\web\User
   {

       private function getGroupId()
       {
           $identity = $this->getIdentity();

           return $identity !== null ? $identity->group_id : null;
       }

       /**
        * @inheritdoc - using getGroupId() instead of getId()
        */
       public function can($permissionName, $params = [], $allowCaching = true)
       {
           $auth = Yii::$app->getAuthManager();
           if ($allowCaching && empty($params) && isset($this->_access[$permissionName])) {
               return $this->_access[$permissionName];
           }
           $access = $auth->checkAccess($this->getGroupId(), $permissionName, $params);
           if ($allowCaching && empty($params)) {
               $this->_access[$permissionName] = $access;
           }

           return $access;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Redefine app user component class in your config file:

   ```
       'components'          => [
           'user'         => [
               'class'   => 'app\models\User',
                ...
           ],
           ...
        ]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be useful

```
    $model = new AuthAssignment();
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
    $auth->assign($auth->getRole('admin'), Yii::$app->user->getId());
```

Comment: i cannot use getId() function. i want to assign the currently logged in user some role

Comment: If you wont the logged user, you can use Yii::$app->user->id